# Disable webpack's require.ensure

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using require.ensure to create chunks. The snippet that I am using looks like below.

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  require("./polyfill.js");
});
```

Now, I want to disable the require.ensure functionality without manually removing/commenting out the

```
// require.ensure([], function(require) {
  require("./polyfill.js");
// });
```

I could partially achieve this with webpack config's parser option

```
module: {
  rules: [{ parser: { requireEnsure: false } }]
}
```

However, this configuration will never require polyfill.js.

If require.ensure is disabled, Webpack should require the polyfill.js and include it the bundle. Otherwise, it should create a chunk.

Edit:
I found a babel-plugin that does this.
[babel-plugin-transform-ensure-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-ensure-ignore)

Still searching for any Webpack solution.